# Am I doing this data-menu-top properly? Do I need to change my layout entirely to get this to work?

Tags: skrollr

I'm using data-menu-top on this page because everything is fixed and uses Skrollr to animate the different sections into view. The reason everything is fixed is so that I could do full-page SVGs that cover the height of the page (if you think there's a better way to do this, I would love to be enlightened).

Here's a link to the project development page: http://pman.mindevo.com

The button that appears on the first section has `data-menu-top="10300"`, and this works great on Chrome, but when I try to view it in Firefox (33.0) the link doesn't do anything at all.

I am initializing using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {
    var s = skrollr.init({
    });

    skrollr.menu.init(s, {
  easing: 'quadratic',
  duration: function(currentTop, targetTop) {
    return 1500;
  }
});
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Am I properly using data-menu-top? Is this a bug I'm not aware of using fixed layouts that are hidden using height?

Do I need to change the layout somehow to accomplish what I want and have it work in Firefox?

Comment: Try to avoid `position:fixed`. An animation to the next section while restricting scroll would be much better IMO. Or better yet, let them scroll if they'd like but allow a button to animate to the next section as well

Comment: I'm not sure that it's possible to have all my different sections of parallax here exist in the same place layering how they are without using position:fixed on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem with Firefox was the way that it handles `<button>` linking. Here's the way the button was in the HTML:

```
<button class="buy buypotato">
    <a data-menu-top="10300" href="#potatoPurchase1" class="purchase-options first-popup-link">
       <svg ....etc></svg>
</button>
```

In Firefox it wasn't doing anything upon clicking, and got me thinking perhaps I'm using "button" HTML element incorrectly. Anyways, changing it to a div like so:

```
<div class="buy buypotato">
    <a data-menu-top="10300" href="#potatoPurchase1" class="purchase-options first-popup-link">
       <svg ....etc></svg>
</div>
```

That allowed Firefox to utilize Skrollr-menu to scroll to where I needed it to.

There might be a better way to do the layout on this, I'm still experimenting.